# jQuery .accordion() resizes weird with video tags inside

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div with video tags inside and my jQuery has .accordion() on that div. When I click on one of the other ones, it resizes the div inside to full width for a split second and then to the correct specified width. Is there a fix for this?
For example, when I click on the 'Series 2' header, Series 1 collapses like it should and when Series 2 opens up, it expands the width of the screen for a split second before going back to its original width.

Code:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="stitle">Series 1</h3>

    <div class="viddiv>
        <h3 class="vidtitle">Video 1</h3>
        <div class="inner">
            <video controls preload="auto" width="600px" height="240px">
                <source src="myVid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

        <h3 class="vidtitle">Video 2</h3>
        <div class="inner">
            <video controls preload="auto" width="600px" height="240px">
                <source src="myVid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="stitle">Series 2</h3>
    <div class="viddiv">
        <h3 class="vidtitle">Video 3</h3>
        <div class="inner">
            <video controls preload="auto" width="600px" height="240px">
                <source src="myVid3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

        <h3 class="vidtitle">Video 4</h3>
        <div class="inner">
            <video controls preload="auto" width="600px" height="240px">
                <source src="myVid4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to include the attribute `heightStyle: "content"`

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#general" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
   });
 });
```

in your accordian function, a working example here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf5Ns/)

Comment: This does not work, it still slides open as full width before scaling down to the div's regular width.

Comment: can you create a JsFiddle of your example ?

Comment: When I made a JsFiddle, it worked. For some reason, it does not work locally, on any browser. It might be the version of jQuery I am using. Also, it only happens when one is closing and the other is opening. If they are both closed, and I open one of them, they drop right down without the weird resize issue.

Comment: If we are allowed to share our YouTube videos, here is the problem: http://youtu.be/D2_Me5ATq_4
If not, I understand if this video is taken down. Thanks!

Comment: if you embed YouTube video code, they come with default size(they can be edited). Ensure your parent DIV is bigger than the video width.

Comment: I am using local files, not embedded YouTube video code. The parent div is in fact larger than the video divs. I also tried to change the size of the parent div to give it more room, and the same thing happened.

Comment: Without looking into the actual code, I dont want to jump into any conclusion. As you said above, it work in JSFiddle.So wold need to look into your actual fiddle.